# Test the Absolute convergence or divergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

∑(0to infinity) (−)^*(/)
This is the question to check it's absolute convergence or divergence
I tried it by using lebintz test which states that lim(n->oo)|Un|=0 for convergence.
Thus when we do it we get that the above series isn't convergening it should be than oscilating
How should I proceed and what should I apply?

Comment: The general term does not tend to $0$, so it is divergent.

Comment: Could you please explain it a bit more ,because I found out it  to be oscilating

Comment: For a series $\sum a_n$ to be convergent it is necessary that $a_n \to 0$. When this fails no other test is necessary.